# Emulator 1 terminated while waiting for it to register

Tags: eclipse, macos, java-me

While I running Jave ME project via Eclipse and Jave_ME_SDK_3 on Mac OS, it prompt an error on the console.I am getting Following Error

```
Failed to connect to device 1!
Reason:
Emulator 1 terminated while waiting for it to register
```

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: I reset the network setting , it is become ok!